# Why in argument section is happen multiplication(recursion)?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Why in argument section is happen multiplication, inside else statement?

```
function main(x, y) {
    if (y === 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return x * main(x, y - 1); // Why in argument section is happen multiplication
    }
}
main(2, 3);
```

Comment: what do you want to get solved exactly? that's a recursive function which returns a multiplication of x and the result of calling the function itself with x and y-1.

Comment: `main === Math.pow` for integer x and non-negative integer y...

Answer (score 0):

I presume this code does what `Math.pow()` function does (in a different way). The first argument is the base and the second argument is the power. `main(x, y)` here, raises `x` to power `y`, which can be achieved by multiplying `x`, `y` times.

I'll try to expand this with each pass:-

1. main(2,3);
   returns 2* main(2, 2);
2. main(2, 2);
   return 2* main(2, 1);
3. main(2, 1);
   return 2* main(2, 0);
4. main(2, 0)
   return 1;

Using (2),(3),(4) in (1), we get:

2 * 2 * 2 * 1;

Answer (score 0):

It is a recursive function, without the check for y==0 the function would never stop.

Now it is calculated like this

```
2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * 1)))
```

Where y is

```
      3    2    1    0
```

Answer (score -1):

Because that's how you calculate exponents.